# Domain Redirect from domain.com/pathA to domainA.com

Tags: iis, dns, redirect, http-redirect

I have an IIS web server that is setup to handle all requests to *.myapp.com. We also have clients that have setup a custom domain, e.g. custom.customer.com as a CNAME To customer.myapp.com

I have a requirement to handle the following:

- Requests to custom.customer.com/pathA will need to be redirected to a.internal-app.com
- Requests to custom.customer.com/pathB will need to be redirected to b.internal-app.com

The problem I have right now is that this can't be done on the DNS level (as it involves paths). Also, whatever the "redirect" is I want the client to see his custom domain at all times. Like he should never see internal-app.com or myapp.com.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with reverse proxy.

1) You need to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS

2) Enable ARR. On the `Application Request Routing` page, select `Enable proxy`

3) Create rewrite rule

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
           <rule name="rewrite custom.customer.com/patha" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="patha" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^custom.customer.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://a.internal-app.com/" />
            </rule>
           <rule name="rewrite custom.customer.com/pathB" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="pathb" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^custom.customer.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://b.internal-app.com/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

P.S. You might have problem with your resources(images,styles,css,js). Because your html might contains absolute paths to resources

You can check this post, when author is creating outbound rule for fixing relative urls https://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr